# How broadcast ping works?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming, broadcast

Hi
Can someone tell me why when I send broadcast ICMP Request, only router send me ICMP Reply?
Even if I modify MAC destination of this ICMP Request (original is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF) to MAC  specific host (IP still broadcast that local network ...it still don't send me Reply.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From RFC1122: "An ICMP Echo Request destined to an IP broadcast or IP multicast address MAY be silently discarded"

MS Windows usually discard broadcast ping. Check that your computers are really running MS Windows.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass this? Modify some fields in whole ethernet packet or sth?

Comment: @Saint_pl looks like there no way, read here http://www.openg.info/entry/broadcast-ping-windows-lan

Comment: @Saint_pl why do you need it?

Comment: I write app that's looking for sniffer in my LAN. Of course I can test each host singly but I'd like to do this at one go.